# Does negative vote count in score gained in tags after deletion

Tags: support, tags, deleted-answers, tag-score

If the post got negative votes and is deleted, does that negative vote after deletion count in the *score of tags*.(Reputation lost is credited back but what about the score of the tags involved in them)  .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scores(negative or positive) on deleted answers will not be calculated on tag scores.
The tag scores are calculated on daily basis, so the tag score will be updated within a day of deletion.

Answer (score 5):

It's not. It's as if the answer never existed in the first place, so none of the votes on it count at all.